# Bootstrap Card Column Padding/Margin Overflow

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, card

I'm trying to split a dictionary of items into three columns using bootstrap Card Column but the padding of bottom rows seems to spill into the top of the next column (see col1->col2). Is there a fix for this?

[Padding/margin overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5W4o.png)

Here's the code:

```
<div class='container p-2 mt-2 mb-4 rounded shadow-lg' style='background-color: #d3b273;'>
            <!-- Dropdown -->
            <div class="btn-group w-100 pb-2">
                <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control border-secondary text-center col-10" value={{selected_agency}}>
                <button type="button" id="agency_dropdown_menu" class="btn dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split col-2 bg-white rounded border-secondary" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu border-secondary w-100 dropdown-menu-right scrollable-menu">
                    {% for agency in agencies %}
                        <button class="dropdown-item border-secondary" name='agency-button' type="submit" value='{{agency}}'>{{agency}}</button>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Fields and values -->
            <div class='card-columns pb-2'>
                {% for field in headers %}
                {% with agency_dict|dictionarylookup:field.name as val %}
                {% ifequal val "" %}
                {% else %}
                <div class="d-flex flex-row card_" style='display: inline-block;'>
                    <div class='d-flex flex-row p-2 m-1 rounded' style='background-color: #8f6e2d; display: inline-block;'>
                        <h4 class='mb-1 mr-3 text-center text-white'>{{field.verbose_name}}:</h3>
                        <p class='m-0 align-self-center' style='color: #edd290;'>{{agency_dict|dictionarylookup:field.name}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endifequal %}
                {% endwith %}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>

<style>
.card-columns {
    column-count: 3;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap **card-columns** use child class's of **card** and will fill its respective column.

Wrapping your **card_** with a **card** class container is the intended implementation of card-columns.

```
<div class="card-columns">

  <div class="card" style='background-color: #8f6e2d'>
      <div class='d-flex flex-row p-2 m-1'>
        <h4 class='mb-1 mr-3 text-center text-white'>{{field.verbose_name}}:</h4>
        <p class='m-0 align-self-center' style='color: #edd290;'>{{agency_dict|dictionarylookup:field.name}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Although this will fix your issue of the cards overflowing to another column you may not get the intended look your after with this solution.

I am not 100% sure on how you wish this dictionary pair to look. Bootstrap card-columns may not be the ideal choice for this. Going off your screen grab.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't seem to work. While I did add the card class (and left out the background color change), it just made it look like this https://imgur.com/yfT1PZa

EDIT: Actually nevermind, that wasn't updated. Wrapping did work, thank you!